# Load a Type from Assembly using simple class name

Tags: c#, reflection

I try to load a type by reflection

I successfully found the assembly containing the type :

```
 var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetTypes().Any(g => g.Name == "MyClass"));
```

but when I try to load the type from the assembly like so :

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("MyClass");
```

Then `t` is null, 
I don't want to load the type using the full qualifying name, just the class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use full qualifying name you need to search via LINQ and manually handle the case, where more than one class is found:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.Name == "MyClass");
var firstType = types.FirstOrDefault();
```

Remember/lesson: there could be more than one class in assembly with the same name (classes that have different namespaces).

Comment: Alternatively the OP can also use Single (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to enforce the existence of a single type with that class name.